# Cómo hacer un regex que coincida con varios inicios con diferentes letras

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo que validar una palabra que puede iniciar con `y`, `g` o `h`.

Por ejemplo, puede ser `yugo...`, `hugo...` o `gugo...`.

```
var original = "gugoss",
    regex    = /[ygh]/,                      
    coincid  = original.match(regex);  
console.log(coincid);
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que coincida con 1 de esas letras al inicio del String, sin importar el resto de los caracteres que contenga?

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el objetivo o la pregunta? Como se describe en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info, se debe incluir **el resultado esperado** y excepciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Match* te encuentra el string dentro de la cadena que provees, que haga match con la expresión regular que tú le estás pasando y te la devuelve como un arreglo de objetos (en caso de que encuentre).

Para hacer lo que indicas en tu pregunta puedes usar ***[test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)*** desde la expresión regular y pasándole de parámetro la cadena a validar. El siguiente código te regresa true si la cadena que le indicas empieza con *y, s* ó *m*.

```js
var original = "yugoss",
    regex    = /^[ysm]/,                      
    coincid  = regex.test(original);  //Regresa true
console.log(coincid);

var original = "iugoss",
    regex    = /^[ysm]/,                      
    coincid  = regex.test(original);  //Regresa false
console.log(coincid);
```

**NOTA:** Observa que es necesario utilizar **`^`** para indicarle que buscará, en este caso, [al comienzo de la cadena](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-caret). Si lo omites te regresará true si la cadena tiene alguno de esos caracteres del regex en todo el cuerpo.