# Coincidir con una letra al inicio del string

Tags: java, regex

Hice el siguiente código:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher; 
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 
import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class 

// one class needs to have a main() method 
public class HelloWorld 
{ 
    // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

          String ori = "kdya"; 
          String pa = "[kd]"; 
          Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(pa); 
          Matcher mat = pat.matcher(ori); 
          System.out.println(mat.matches()); 

    } 
}
```

Quiero emparejar el inicio del String original (el primer carácter) con cualquier carácter de la lista del patrón.

No empareja, pero sí que existe. ¿Qué está mal?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con emparejar el inicio del string original con cualquier caracter de la lista del patrón?

Comment: @deluf para estos casos es recomendable que incluyas toda la información que se solicita en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info incluyendo el objetivo que estás buscando, en el sentido de si sólo te interesa ver si coincide o no, o si te interesa obtener otra informacion. Siempre se deberían incluir diferentes ejemplos, excepciones, y resultado esperado.

Comment: @deluf Además, si ya habías recibido una respuesta de [cómo realizarlo en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/69537/127) horas antes, ¿No te parece que al menos deberías haber intentado con ese regex? ¿o al menos intentar entenderlo antes de hacer otra pregunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu regex acepta cadenas de longitud 1 que contengan la k o la s.
Prueba con `String original = "k";` y verás que imprime true.

Para que tu regex acepte cualquier cadena que empiece por k o por s debes usar:

```
[ks].*

[ks] Acepta un solo caracter de entre los especificados.
.    Acepta cualquier carácter. Pero solo 1. (*)
*    Modifica el elemento anterior (el .) haciendo que acepte
    cualquier cantidad de 0 a infinito.
```

(*) Que acepte o no terminadores de línea es configurable pero esto se sale del tema.

Answer (score 3):

El método [`Matcher#matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) intenta que un regex coincida con un texto completamente, de principio a fin. Prácticamente no existen casos en los que uno debería usar este método.

En cambio, para el comportamiento estándar de expresiones regulares, y poder buscar coincidencias en cualquier lugar del texto, se utiliza el método [**`Matcher#find()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--).

En regex, el caracter especial `^` coincide con la posición al inicio del texto (ver en la descripción de [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher; 
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
String texto = "kdya"; 
String regex = "^[kd]"; 
Pattern pat  = Pattern.compile(regex); 
Matcher mat  = pat.matcher(texto);

if (mat.find())  // ⬅️⬅️⬅️ Se compara con .find()
{
    System.out.println("El texto '" + texto + "' empieza con " + mat.group()); 
}
else
{
    System.out.println("No coincide");
}
```

[<kbd>Demo en ideone</kbd>](http://ideone.com/JCacfL)

---

> **Nota:** entiendo que es un caso con el que estás practicando. De lo contrario, es mucho más sencillo usar [`String#startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):
>
> ```
> if (texto.startsWith("k") || texto.startsWith("d")) {
>     //...
> }
> ```